# Online Data Bank

Tags: categorical-data, dataset, internet

Is it possible to find an online data bank?
I mean a site  that contains many data observations for different types of data, just ready to analyze.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few "classical" data sets that get used quite often for practice.

From my experience some of the common ones are:

- [The Iris data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)
- [The Auto MPG data set](https://data.world/databeats/auto-mpg-data-set)
- [MT cars](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/mtcars.html)

If you want more of a complete set of data from more of a real world field [Kaggle](https://kaggle.com) is a very popular online community of users whose specific goal is to post real world data they want specific insights on. They often have competitions where you can even win cash prizes.

Answer (score 1):

[UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php), maybe?